# Convert mysql raw query contain nested join to laravel eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I need to implement this raw query with laravel Eloquent based on table1 model :

```
SELECT e.* FROM table1 e
INNER JOIN 
  ( 
    SELECT et.table1_id FROM table1_table2 et
    INNER JOIN table1 e ON e.id = et.table1_id
    INNER JOIN tags t ON t.id = et.tag_id
    WHERE t.id IN(@tags) 
    GROUP BY et.table1_id 
    HAVING COUNT(et.tag_id) = @x
  ) ee ON e.id = ee.table1_id
JOIN table1_table2 ON table1_table2.table1_id = e.id
JOIN tags ON tags.id = table1_table2.tag_id 
GROUP BY table1_table2.table1_id
```

`@tag` var is comma separated integer and `@x` var is count of `@tag` var.

there are some ralation between tags table1 and table1_table2 :

In table1 model we have:

```
public function tags()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Tag::class, 'table1_table2', 'table1_id', 'tag_id');
}
```

my larave version is 5.8.35

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Just convert it to eloquent, or combine it with relationship? Because `tags` relationship isn't a `join`. It's another query. I mean, It will produce 2 queries if you use eloquent relationship, not a single query with `join` like your raw query.